# Best solution for dynamic account connection in C?

Tags: c, libpurple

I'm not very familiar with C design patterns and searching for the best solution for the following problem. I want to write a little chat client based on libpurple.

While running the program I want to be able to connect and disconnect several instant message accounts. The connect and disconnect calls should be passed over command line, but waiting for input with gets(); is no solution, because the program should run all the time getting new messages from the already connected instant message accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `poll` (or `select`) for handling the events. So after establishing the connections, you have the file descriptors, and in addition you have the standard input, which also has a file descriptor from the OS (namely 0), and you can pass all those file descriptors to `poll`, which notifies you when there is incoming data on any of the file descriptors. Example code:

```
/* fd1, fd2 are sockets */
while(1) {
    pollfd fds[3];
    int ret;

    fds[0].fd = fd1;
    fds[1].fd = fd2;
    fds[2].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[1].events = POLLIN;
    fds[2].events = POLLIN;
    ret = poll(fds, 3, -1); /* poll() blocks, but you can set a timeout here */
    if(ret < 0) {
        perror("poll");
    }
    else if(ret == 0) {
        printf("timeout\n");
    }
    else {
        if(fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            /* incoming data from fd1 */
        }
        if(fds[0].revents & (POLLERR | POLLNVAL)) {
            /* error on fd1 */
        }
        if(fds[1].revents & POLLIN) {
            /* incoming data from fd2 */
        }
        if(fds[1].revents & (POLLERR | POLLNVAL)) {
            /* error on fd2 */
        }
        if(fds[2].revents & POLLIN) {
            /* incoming data from stdin */
            char buf[1024];
            int bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1024);
            /* handle input, which is stored in buf */
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't mention the OS. This works for POSIX (OS X, Linux, Windows with mingw). If you need to use the Win32 API, it'll look a bit different but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out select(2). I'm not really sure how libpurple works, but if it allows notification via file-descriptor (like a file or socket), then select is your solution.

You could also try creating a seperate thread with pthread_create(3). That way it can block on gets (or whatever) while the rest of your program does it's thing.